# LoadError on Ruby

Tags: ruby, atom-editor

I just installed Atom text editor and Ruby, typed a single line of ruby code in the Atom text editor; puts "Hello world" but the Atom Runner returns with an error message;

> ruby: No such file or directory --
>   C:/Users/OKaro/Desktop/Ruby/example.rb (LoadError).

How can I fix this?

Am using a Windows 10 PC, running ruby 2.5.3p105
Atom    : 1.35.1
Electron: 2.0.18

I have tried running the ruby code with command prompt and it works perfectly. giving me the desired `Hello world` output

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out what your current working directory is for your running script.

Add this line at your code:

```rb
puts Dir.pwd
```

This code print's the path of your file.

Then check if your atom-runner is configured to accept ruby scripts on config.cson file (Atom -> Config) like atom-runner documentation says to do

[Atom-runner](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner)

```
"*":
....
'runner':
    'scopes':
      'coffee': 'coffee'
      'js': 'node'
      'ruby': 'ruby'
```